# How to get issuer name in RFC-1779 from X509Certificate2?

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate2

The `Issuer` property from `X509Certificate2` returns a `string` such as:

"CN=eBusiness Development CA, OU=ITSB eBusiness Systems Team, O=AVANO, L=Sydney, S=NSW, C=AU"

How do I get the same in RFC-1779? For example:

"/C=AU/ST=NSW/L=Sydney/O=AVANO/OU=ITSB eBusiness Systems Team/CN=eBusiness Development CA"

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, password);
Console.WriteLine(cert.Issuer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you're wanting is just the reverse of the string you're actually getting from `Issuer`, and is delimited by slashes instead of commas with a following space.

My first attempt to solve this problem was to create a new `X500DistinguishedName` object, passing the certificate's `IssuerName` and `X500DistinguishedNameFlags.Reversed` to the constructor:

```
var distinguishedName = new X500DistinguishedName(cert.Issuer, X500DistinguishedNameFlags.Reversed);
```

But that didn't provide me with the result I was hoping for. I'm not sure of any baked in way to do this. But you could try reformatting the string manually to meet your needs:

```
var split = cert.Issuer.Split(new []{',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var reversed = split.Reverse();
var finalIssuerName = string.Join("/", reversed);
```